# How to forget previous plots - how can I flush/refresh?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you get `matplotlib.pyplot` to "forget" previous plots

I am trying to plot multiple time using `matplotlib.pyplot`

The code looks like this:

```
def plottest():
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    a=np.random.rand(10,)
    b=np.random.rand(10,)
    c=np.random.rand(10,)


    plt.plot(a,label='a')
    plt.plot(b,label='b')
    plt.plot(c,label='c')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.ylabel('mag')
    plt.xlabel('element)')
    plt.show()

    e=np.random.rand(10,)
    f=np.random.rand(10,)
    g=np.random.rand(10,)


    plt.plot(e,label='e')
    plt.plot(f,label='f')
    plt.plot(g,label='g')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.ylabel('mag')
    plt.xlabel('element)')
    plt.show()
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the same plot (actually from some other code which I ran and completed a while ago) no matter what I do.

Similar code has worked previously for me.

I have looked at these questions:

[How to "clean the slate"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819363/how-to-clean-the-slate)

[Matplotlib pyplot show() doesn't work once closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158447/matplotlib-pyplot-show-doesnt-work-once-closed?rq=1)

[(python) matplotlib pyplot show() .. blocking or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187603/python-matplotlib-pyplot-show-blocking-or-not)

and tried using `plt.show()`, `plt.clf()` and `plt.close` to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I would rather use `plt.clf()` after every `plt.show()` to **just clear the current figure** instead of closing and reopening it, keeping the window size and giving you a better performance and much better memory usage.

Similarly, you could do `plt.cla()` **to just clear the current [axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html)**.

To clear a specific [axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html), useful when you have multiple axes within one figure, you could do for example:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

axes[0, 1].clear()
```

Comment: My problem was solved without [0, 1]. Not sure why you did it.

Answer (score 62):

I discovered that this behaviour only occurs after running a particular script, similar to the one in the question. I have no idea why it occurs.

It works (refreshes the graphs) if I put

```
plt.clf()
plt.cla()
plt.close()
```

after every `plt.show()`

Comment: The `plt.cla()` call after `plt.clf()` is redundant: the latter already clears the figure *including* the axes, so there is nothing left to clear.