# Python Equivalent for MATLAB chi2ogf(x)

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, statistics, probability

I was wondering if there's a function similar to MATLAB chi2gf(x) to determine the goodness of fit

if so , do I still need to calcualte the P-Value or it's the same thing ?

[Matlab chi2gf(x)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with `scipy` then [`scipy.stats.chisquare`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) might be a good choice.

Comment: Thank you so much , I believe it's ddof : chisquare([16, 18, 16, 14, 12, 12], ddof=[0,1,2])
(2.0, array([ 0.84914504,  0.73575888,  0.5724067 ])) that I should use

Comment: What I could not manage is that what should I apply for ddof in my code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634119/python-keeps-overwriting-hist-on-previous-plot-but-doesnt-save-it-with-the-desi/51648079?noredirect=1#comment90260012_51648079

Comment: In the code ddof is not exaplained, I found it here : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.var.html but not sure what it does in Chisquare

Comment: Do you have any idea about ddof ? I am still unsuccessfull in finding some results

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti I'm afraid I can't help you with this :(

Comment: still it was a very effective answer, Thank you