# updating a 3d python plot during a convergence iteration

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I try to create a plotting script that plots my data in two 3d structures (with one variable as a color) that I use in a loop in which the data is supposed to converge. I would like to update the figure every iteration, instead of creating a new figure. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def colorplot_3D(network, color_variable_1, color_variable_2):

    net = network

    X, Y, Z = net['pore.coords'][net.Ps].T
    X_max, Y_max, Z_max = np.amax(X), np.amax(Y), np.amax(Z)

    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')
    plot_1 = ax.scatter(xs=X, ys=Y, zs=Z, c=color_variable_1)
    plt.xlabel('x-position')
    plt.ylabel('y-position')
    cbar_1 = fig.colorbar(plot_1)
    ax.text(X_max / 2, 0, Z_max * 1.2, 'membrane')
    ax.text(X_max / 2, Y_max, Z_max * 1.2, 'current collector')
    ax.text(-0.2 * X_max, Y_max / 2, Z_max * 1.2, 'flow inlet')
    ax.text(1.3 * X_max, Y_max / 2, Z_max * 1.2, 'flow outlet')
    cbar_1.ax.set_ylabel('pore concentration [mol/m3]')

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, projection='3d')
    plot_2 = ax2.scatter(xs=X, ys=Y, zs=Z, c=color_variable_2)
    cbar_2 = fig.colorbar(plot_2)
    cbar_2.ax.set_ylabel('liquid potential [V]')
    ax2.text(X_max / 2, 0, Z_max * 1.2, 'membrane')
    ax2.text(X_max / 2, Y_max, Z_max * 1.2, 'current collector')
    ax2.text(-0.2 * X_max, Y_max / 2, Z_max * 1.2, 'flow inlet')
    ax2.text(1.3 * X_max, Y_max / 2, Z_max * 1.2, 'flow outlet')
    plt.draw()

    return fig
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question, that way this question will be marked accordingly for future users

Comment: Take a look at [matplotlib-animations](https://brushingupscience.com/2019/08/01/elaborate-matplotlib-animations). (Are your plots on the web anywhere ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you could do this would be

- Use a combination of `set_offsets()` and `set_3d_properties`
- Clear the `figure` and/or `axes` object(s) and plot a new `scatter` every iteration

---

**Example using `set_offsets()` and `set_3d_properties`:**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, 25)
y = np.sin(x)
z = np.cos(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

def plot(ax):
    return ax.scatter(x, y, z)

def update(s):
    s.set_offsets(np.stack([x, y], 1))
    s.set_3d_properties(z, 'z')

s = plot(ax)
plt.savefig("./before.png")
y = np.cos(x)
z = np.sin(x)
update(s)
plt.savefig("./after.png")
```

**Example clearing and redrawing:**

```py
def plot(fig, ax):
    ax.scatter(x, y, z)

plot(fig, ax)
plt.savefig("./before.png")
y = np.cos(x)
z = np.sin(x)
plt.cla()
plot(fig, ax)
plt.savefig("./after.png")
```

Or, if you want to accumulate the data from every iteration in the same scatter plot, you can just append the new data points to the `x`, `y`, and `z` objects and use one of the above methods.

**Example with accumulation:**

```py
def plot(ax):
    return ax.scatter(x, y, z)

def update(s):
    s.set_offsets(np.stack([x, y], 1))
    s.set_3d_properties(z, 'z')

s = plot(ax)
plt.savefig("./before.png")
x = np.vstack([x,x])
y = np.vstack([y, np.cos(x)])
z = np.vstack([z, np.sin(x)])
update(s)
plt.savefig("./after.png")
```

I would recommend the combination of `set_offsets()` and `set_3d_properties()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58787960/how-to-correctly-refer-to-fig-and-ax-with-moviepy-animation/59013405#59013405) for more about scoping the `figure` and `axes` objects.