# Image saving with plt needs more and more time

Tags: python, matplotlib, time

I wrote a simple program to convert .wav to spectogram and save this as an png.
Here you go:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import os
import time as t

DATAPATH = 'dataset' #path
CATEGORIES = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']

for categorie in CATEGORIES:
    path = DATAPATH + '/' + categorie + '/'
    filenames = os.listdir(path) #get all filenames in categorie
    print(categorie)

    i = 0
    for file in filenames[:100]:
        start = t.time()
        Fs, aud = wavfile.read(path + file)
        powerSpectrum, frequenciesFound, time, imageAxis = plt.specgram(aud, Fs=Fs)

        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1) #cut axis
        plt.axis('off')

        plt.savefig('pics/' + categorie + '/' + str(i) + '.png')
        ende = t.time()
        print(i, str(ende-start)+'s')
        i += 1
```

The problem is that the time per image getiing higher and higher (only for  a few milisekonds) but at the thousand pic it will be like 10sek per pic. Thats why I stopp the time and print it out. Some solutions?

Comment: Your output plots look how they should? It sounds like the plot is accumulating stuff instead of flushing after every iteration. Does this question help? [matplotlib.pyplot will not forget previous plots - how can I flush/refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106288/matplotlib-pyplot-will-not-forget-previous-plots-how-can-i-flush-refresh)

Comment: @aaossa a lot of thanks you helped me alot and now my code works how it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTR, the solution seems to be cleaning the plot after every iteration using [`plt.clf()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clf.html):

```
for categorie in CATEGORIES:
    # ...
    for file in filenames[:100]:
        # ...
        # plt.savefigs(...)
        plt.clf()
        # ...
```